# Need ideas to amplify high baseline signal

Tags: amplifier, voltage-amplification

I have a liquid level sensor. It is made of two platinum wires submerged in water.

Below is description of working principle:

1. Both wires are alternatingly connected to 3.3V and Analog read pin (to make it kind of AC because with DC ionic migration leades to continuous drop in voltage).
2. Switching is done using four switches in a 4066 IC.
3. Switching frequency is between 5 and 10KHz.
4. Analog voltage is measured and as the water level rises there is a drop in observed voltage.

Below is the image of the circuit with the following change from the principle above:

1. The 3.3V from mains is removed as with that there for some reason a continuous drop in voltage was observed (the DC problem), and also, there was no noticeable effect of drop in voltage with rise in volume.
2. Somehow just the action of switching signals from the Microcontroller is supplying voltage to the electrodes.
3. It has been noticed in the raw analog output that switching is not instantaneous hence there is a continuous 3.3V output. Hence moving average was taken to level out the readings.
   [image]

The problem is that the drop in units value of the averaged output for every 1 ml rise in value is only about 4 points, and only about 9 points for 2.5 ml water level rise.

I would need the moving average to drop at least a hundred points (for each 1 ml water level rise) to have 0.01 ml resolution. How do I do it?

I am using a ESP32 board. The baseline is around 3892 (moving Average value).

Comment: *How do I do it?* <-- use a much higher resolution ADC. Maybe a bespoke delta-sigma ADC would do the job?

Comment: @Andyaka any way to amplify the signal? some electronics magic?

Comment: In order to amplify the signal you need to remove the baseline, which means you need to make the signal AC. It's possible to do it with your switches but your schematic is unreadable.

Comment: @bobflux if it helps I could make a kicad schematic, but I fear that too would be very messy coming out of my hand. The problem with switches is that the microcontroller commands handle one switch at a time, it can't handle all of them at once. Hence there is always a strong DC residue in the final analog output.

Comment: I don't see how this will measure water level. Any resistance you put between 3.3V and ADC input pin should read 3.3V except for the effect of leakage currents. ADCs are not capable of measuring resistance directly, just the voltage at the ADC pin. May I ask how you ended up with this circuit and how you thought it should work? There have been similar water level resistance measuring questions recently.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

[image]

The 4 switches form a bridge that sends AC current through the sensor (in the center). We have three states:

1. S1,S4 closed: positive sensor current
2. S2,S3 closed: negative sensor current
3. All switches open: zero sensor current

The sensor current is turned into a voltage via R2. This is referenced to ground, so it can be amplified by the opamp (make sure to pick an opamp whose input and output can go to zero volts, a rail to rail opamp would be preferable).

The mcu should set the switches, then wait until the signal settles and do an ADC acquisition. The idea is to use the ADC to measure voltage in the three states above. The measurement from state 3, when all switches are off, gives the opamp offset. This can be substracted from the other two measurements to remove the offset.